# Desktop page speed fine, cannot get a passable mobile speed

Tags: wordpress, performance, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I am running a light wordpress installation, with a light theme (neve). I am running a CDN (cloudflare), I am making most optimizations that I can think of with some room around images and custom code stripping.

However I am not even close for my pages and even if I test AMP pages which are stripped down I don't get a passing score which concerns me. Can anyone help me out, for example 1 of my blog post pages:

Amp report:
https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.culturalistpress.com%2Fanycubic-photon-mono-3d-printer-is-it-good-what-materials-can-it-use-what-software-does-it-use-and-how-does-it-compare-to-the-anycubic-mega-series%2F%3Famp%3D1

Not amp report:
https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.culturalistpress.com%2Fanycubic-photon-mono-3d-printer-is-it-good-what-materials-can-it-use-what-software-does-it-use-and-how-does-it-compare-to-the-anycubic-mega-series%2F

In both cases my main thread processing is too much and too much JS - short of that I don't see a lot of savings. Most the JS comes from ads which I don't understand why they are blocking in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your both reports, the man issue is with Javascript. As your website has developed in WordPress use some 3rd party plugin like WProcket and perfmatters to reduce unused Javascript. Your page DOM size, it is created when you have too many sections in your page. Try to reduce those sections to reduce the page size, minimize the gap between paragraphs.

Adjust the images size and try to use WEBP format of images. Also check the compatibility of third party plugins with you WordPress version which you have installed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).